# ES6 import and export does not work

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

In a react app i using this scripts with priority :

```
jquery-3.3.1.js

es6.js

react.js

react-dom.js

react-with-addons.js

react-router.js

react-router-dom.js

browser.js

bootstrap.js
```

when I create class like this :

```
class className
```

Have no error  and react working good, but when I create my class like this :

```
export class className
```

Browser occured me an error message :  "exports is not defined"

Comment: The error suggests that you use `exports` and not `export`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not really show the part producing the error. But the error suggests that you are using `exports` instead of `export`.

Comment: thanks for answer, now i have an other question 
Uncaught SyntaxError: http://my component.js: Unexpected token (1:8)
> 1 | exports class CategoryEdit extends React.Component {
    |                 ^
  2 |     constructor(props) {
etc...

Comment: Hi A.J., if you have another question you should post another question. You should also read the community guidelines to see how you should formulate your question to get more and better answers.